# Is "choosing" considered as some sort of "chance" in probability?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, bayes-theorem

There are 3 baskets. Basket 1 contains 4 red balls and 2 green balls. Basket 2 contains 6 red balls, 3 green balls, and 1 yellow ball. Basket 3 contains 5 red balls and 5 green balls. If I got a green ball, what is the probability that the basket I chose was basket 1?

I am not sure if the term "chose" was some hint that would suggest that I should treat the problem differently?

Anyway, here's my approach:
$B_1$ = Basket 1
$B_2$ = Basket 2
$B_3$ = Basket 3

$p(R|B_1) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{4}{6}\right) = 0.22$
$p(G|B_1) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{2}{6}\right) = 0.11$
$p(Y|B_1) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{0}{6}\right) = 0$

$p(R|B_2) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{6}{10}\right) = 0.2$
$p(G|B_2) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{3}{10}\right) = 0.1$
$p(Y|B_2) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{10}\right) = 0.03$

$p(R|B_3) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{5}{10}\right) = 0.167$
$p(G|B_2) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{5}{10}\right) = 0.167$
$p(Y|B_2) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{0}{10}\right) = 0$

Using Bayes' Theorem:
\begin{align*}
p(B_1|G) &= \dfrac{p(G|B_1)}{p(G|B_1) + p(G|B_2) + p(G|B_3)}\\
&= \dfrac{0.11}{0.11 + 0.1 + 0.167}\\
&= \dfrac{0.11}{0.377}\\
&= \dfrac{0.11}{0.377}\\
&= 0.29 = 29\%
\end{align*}

Please tell me if my approach was right.

Comment: Seems right after a scan. You should probably write $p(B_1|G)$ before your first equality, and maybe mention Bayes theorem.

Comment: Thanks. This might sound obvious but, just want to ask if the case was that I got a Yellow key, what are the chances that it is from basket 1? Is it 0?

Comment: yes, the word chance and probability here is used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. Words such as "choose", "pick", "select", "draw", etc... are usually meant in their literal English sense and involve no hidden things. Sometimes the probability of getting something is higher than the rest but that Is usually mentioned (example: a coin where the probability of getting head is $0.70$), what you should pay attention to is if the choice is made with or without replacement as that leads to a totally different answer.
That being said, your solution is correct.